# Pop Up ViewController from Navigation Stack

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm studying the tutorial from Apple Developer: [Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/index.html), and I'm confused with push and modal segue.

There are two scenarios, Save and Cancel button in navigation bar, backing to scene 1 from scene 2.

If the Cancel button is pressed, it will call different method for dismissing scene 2:

```
@IBAction func cancel(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // Depending on style of presentation (modal or push presentation), this view controller needs to be dismissed in two different ways.
    let isPresentingInAddMealMode = presentingViewController is UINavigationController

    if isPresentingInAddMealMode {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else if let owningNavigationController = navigationController{
        owningNavigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    else {
        fatalError("The MealViewController is not inside a navigation controller.")
    }
}
```

In this method, if the scene is presented by modal segue, dismiss(animated:completion:) is called, and
if the scene is presented by push segue, popViewController(animated:) is called for poping up the ViewController from the navigation stack.

But for the Save button, the tutorial overrides a method in scene 2, prepare(for:sender:), and a action method in scene 1, unwindToMealList(sender:).
And it drag the Save button to Exit (the button in the scene dock) and choose unWindToMealList(sender:) method.
So the flow will be: prepare(for:sender:) -> scene 2 dismissed and scene 1 presented -> unWindToMealList(sender:)

I'm wondering that the code snippets didn't dismiss explictly scene 2 and remove the ViewController in navigation stack when Save button is pressed.
I know that modal segue won't push ViewController to navigation stack, but push segue will push it.
Why the code snippets doesn't pop up it from navigation stack?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the tutorial you are reading is making use of [*unwind segues*](https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/create-unwind-segues-in-swift-3-8793f7d23c6f).

Unwind segues, just like normal segues, have a source and a destination and you can prepare for it in `prepareForSegue`, but instead of presenting the destination VC, it will dismiss the source VC so that the destination VC is shown.

Unwind segues behave differently in different situations. When you present VC B from VC A using a push segue, and an unwind segue from B to A, the unwind segue will pop VC B from the navigation stack. When you present VC B from VC A modally, the unwind segue will dismiss the modally presented VC.

As you can see, unwind segues are quite smart. It will decide for itself what to do in order to show the destination VC. It can even pop two or more VCs in the navigation stack!